# Firefox/Chrome extension: how to open link when new tab is created?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Working on a [Firefox WebExtension](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions).

The code below works when I open a new tab, but it is updating any current tab when I click on a link.

How can I use `query` to select **only** the new tabs?
Is there another way to do this?

```
/* Load Google when creates a new tab. */

function openMyPage() {
  //console.log("injecting");
   chrome.tabs.query({
     'currentWindow': true,
     'active': true
    // This will match all tabs to the pattern we specified
    }, function(tab) {
        // Go through all tabs that match the URL pattern
        for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            // Update those tabs to point to the new URL
            chrome.tabs.update(
                tab[i].id, {
                    'url': 'http://google.com'
                }
            );
        }
    });
};

//Add openMyPage() as a listener when new tabs are created
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(openMyPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tabs.onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) callback is provided an argument which is a `Tab` object. You should not query to get it, you already have it.

```
function openMyPage(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(
        tab.id, {
            'url': 'http://google.com'
        }
    );
};
```

---

Note that this will indiscriminately target new tabs - even those that the user opened via "open link in new tab". If that's not what you want, you'll need extra logic to detect that it is a New Tab page.

With `"tabs"` permission, the `tab` object will have the property `url` populated. You can use it to filter new tabs. In Chrome, that would be `chrome://newtab/`, in Firefox it should be (I haven't tested) `about:home` or `about:newtab`.